# System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception

Tags: c#, algorithm, xamarin.android, system.drawing

I want to create an application where I can capture an image with Black Background with an Object and pass the image path to the Algorithm to calculate the size of an object in the image.

**What we are doing:** Capturing the image with Black Background with an Object.

**Algorithm:** Algorithm is written in C# Windows compatibility mode. The algorithm remove the black color background and after cropping it returns the size of an Object using (System.Drawing dll).
The algorithm works fine in Desktop application.

We are trying to convert the Application in Xamarin Android. Where we find some issues during Runtime.

**Error:** **System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception. ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.String filename ”**

```
    var bmp = new Bitmap(App._file.Path); //App._file Path Path from camera image
    var filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
    Bitmap grayImage = filter.Apply(bmp);
```

So what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @EvilTak I have edited the question

Comment: The internal Gdip class is a wrapper for GDI+ functions.  It has indeed a static constructor, it needs to call the [GdiplusStartup()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) initialization function.  It can never work on an Android machine, no support for GDI+, and the [DllImport] function will always fail to resolve.  You just can't use System.Drawing.

Comment: @HansPassant is thre any alternative way to achieve (Alternative of System.drawing in Xamarin Android) .In Android we normal use Android.Graphics Framework

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem